Limiting Bandwidth for specific user with Nodejs express-session
I want to distribute my limited bandwidth across all users (both upload and download), and I'm planning to divide like this:

10Mbps for users without session
25Mbps for users with session and session.user === 'foo'
50Mbps for users with session and session.user === 'bar'

I tried stream-throttle using this code:
const { Throttle, ThrottleGroup } = require("stream-throttle");

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.pipe(new Throttle({ rate: 5 * 1024 * 1024 / 8 })); //5Mbps
    next();
});

It still have full speed. Beside that when I try to upload a file through busboy, it only receive about 1 - 2MB before completely stop.
And I tried node-throttle, express-bandwidth-throttle as well and received the same result.
The next() method is required due to handling upload job (busboy)
Here's the upload handler code for more context.
function uploadBusboy(req, res, next) {
console.log('User using Busboy Uploader Method...');
req.pipe(req.busboy); // Pipe it through busboy here

let targetFolderC = '';
let folderName = '';
let numberOfFiles = 0;
let totalFile = 0;
let tempFiles = [];

req.busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    if (fieldname === 'targetFolder') {
        targetFolderC = val;
    }
    if (fieldname === 'folderName') {
        folderName = val;
    }
});

req.busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
    console.log(`Upload of '${filename.filename}' started`);
    numberOfFiles++;
    totalFile++;
    var tempPath = path.join("./public/Uploader/uploadsTemp/", filename.filename);

    tempFiles.push(tempPath);
    // Create a write stream of the new file
    const fstream = fs.createWriteStream(tempPath);
    // Pipe it to the writer, already tried to put .pipe(res) here and doesn't work;
    file.pipe(fstream);

    fstream.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`'${targetFolderC}'`);
        console.log(`Upload of '${filename.filename}' finished`);
        numberOfFiles--;
        if (numberOfFiles <= 0) {
            tempFiles.forEach((temp) => {
                const targetFolder = path.join("./public/Uploader/uploads/", targetFolderC, folderName);

                const oldPath = temp;
                const newPath = path.join(targetFolder, temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf("uploadsTemp") + 12));
                fs.mkdirSync(targetFolder, { recursive: true });
                fs.renameSync(oldPath, newPath);
            });

            console.log(`Received total of ${totalFile} files`);
            res.redirect('back');
        }

    });
});

}

stream-throttle is abandoned, did you try something else? What did you try with express-slow-down and what did go wrong?

express-slow-down is not relevant to this as I mistakenly include to the code. And I tried node-throttle, express-bandwidth-throttle as well and received the same result.

When you call next(), you start next handler immediately, until res.end() will be called in some handler in the chain, without any throttling.
For the throttling to work, you code should looks like this:
req.pipe(new Throttle({ rate: 5 * 1024 * 1024 / 8 })).pipe(res)


I call next() to pass down to the busboy for handling file upload. so it wouldn't make any sense piping the res here.
